# Adding app in Windows Phone gallery

Tags: windows-phone-7, image-gallery

I am new in Windows Phone app development.
I have just created an app which deals with image processing.
I want to add my app to the list shown in the photo gallery and could not find a way to do it.
It would be great if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the WMAppManfiest.xml file using XML Editor. Add `Extensions` after the `Token` element. And Insert extension of `Photos_Extra_Hub` into extensions.

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension ExtensionName="Photos_Extra_Hub"
         ConsumerID="{5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5632}"
         TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

So your app will appear on the Photo Hub Apps. If you want to edit your picture by your app in WP8. You can read [Extending the photo edit picker for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662932%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: thanx @Chris, i can now list my app to the pictures hub but what i wanted was to open my pictures of picture hub from my app directly. can you help me on this.